# Python display list of integers as uppercase hexadecimals

Tags: python

Let's have a list of integers like:

```py
foo = [1, 2, 3, 127, 255]
```

How do I convert it to string which contains uppercase hexadecimal representation like below?

```py
result = "Some text [0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x7F, 0xFF] some text"
```

Was trying to do one liner like:

```py
result = f"Some text {'[{}]'.format(', '.join(hex(bar) for bar in foo))} some text"
```

But it comes with lowercase like:

```
'Some text [0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x7f, 0xff] some text'
```

Comment: `hex(...).upper()` ?

Comment: @jasonharper: That will uppercase the `x` as well, which people *usually* (though not always) don't want. Only sane way to do it is using a formatted string of the form `0x{:X}`, where the `:X` formatting placeholder produces uppercase hex and you manually shove a lowercase `0x` on the front (if using f-strings, you'd need to put the name of the variable being formatted before the `:`).

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger - yes, I meant that `x` to be lowercase, and that's true `.upper` is not applicable in my case.
Also thanks Jason for proposition!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `"0x" + format(bar, 'X')` instead of `hex(bar)`

With f-strings:  `f"0x{bar:X}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatting code `X` for that, which can be used with `str.format` or f-strings. For example:

```
numbers = ', '.join(f'0x{bar:X}' for bar in foo)
result = f"Some text [{numbers}] some text"
```

Be careful about nesting calls to `str.format` and f-strings inside each other, because it quickly becomes very hard to read.